# How Can I Get A Clean Topology While Keeping The Normals Smooth?

Tags: modeling, normals, topology

I'm working on the star destroyer.

I have created the hunger bay at the bottom of it
but while trying to maintain clean topology. The result ended up with normal's that are a bit warped.
Any idea how to fix is while keeping good topology?

https://youtu.be/fRLFHv2eFCc
[image]

I'm also adding the Project file in case everybody can and will to take the time to look into it:

https://we.tl/t-spXh3879N5

Comment: Can you show the normals in your screen captures?  BSE has a mechanism for offering your files. Info offered on other sites can disappear which is undesirable.

Comment: well i was actually able to fix the normal.
but it resulted in an uniformed. topology the thing is i want to add a displacement later on and im afraid it might screw it up

[url=https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic5fc7115555df9488573433][img]https://www.linkpicture.com/q/image_2020-12-01_200015.png[/img][/url]

Comment: if u refere to the face orientation then here you go.
https://www.linkpicture.com/q/image_2020-12-01_202314.png

but again: this is really not the point anymore. the normals are fixed.
the problem now is the topology witch is very not uniformed